# С++ метод половинного деления выводит -nan(ind)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия, методы

все нормально считает ответ
но я не могу его вернуть из функции
только на экран вывожу
на предпоследней итерации ответ верный
а на последней магическим образом становится -nan(ind)
https://pastebin.com/a1vmNua0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

double function(double a, double b, double x) {
    double res;
    res = 1 / x - log(a*x + b);
    return res;
}


double HalfDivisionMethod(double xl, double xr, double eps, double a, double b) {
    double x = (xl + xr) / 2;
    if (abs(function(a, b, x)) < eps) return x;
    double fl = function(a, b, xl);
    double fx = function(a, b, x);
    if (fl*fx < 0) {
        cout <<"x = "<< x <<endl;
        cout << "fl = " << fl << endl;
        cout << "fx = " << fx << endl;
        cout << "xl = " << xl << endl;
        cout << "xr = " << xr << endl;
        cout << "Идем влево" << endl<<endl;

        HalfDivisionMethod(xl, x, eps, a, b);

    }
    else {
        cout << "x = " << x << endl;
        cout << "fl = " << fl << endl;
        cout << "fx = " << fx << endl;
        cout << "xl = " << xl << endl;
        cout << "xr = " << xr << endl;
        cout << "Идем вправо" << endl << endl;
        HalfDivisionMethod(x, xr, eps, a, b);
    }


}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    cout << "Hello, world!";
    cout << HalfDivisionMethod(0.1, 1, 0.00001, 3, 5);
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Заменил на return 5 и все равно ответ nan выдает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум, вы должны рекурсивно вызывать с возвратом значения: не просто

```
HalfDivisionMethod(xl, x, eps, a, b);
HalfDivisionMethod(x, xr, eps, a, b);
```

а

```
return HalfDivisionMethod(xl, x, eps, a, b);
return HalfDivisionMethod(x, xr, eps, a, b);
```

Иначе возврат в самой глубокой рекурсии просто теряется.

А код помещайте в вопрос!

Comment: Спасибо, все верно в этом ошибка была

Comment: Кто бы сомневался :) Если проблема решена, граф :), закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый...